# Router automatically assigning wrong IP to devices

Tags: router, dhcp

Over the last few weeks, my router (Netgear R7000) has automatically set a "wrong" IP address for several devices.

I'm using DHCP with a range of 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.254, but (seemingly) randomly, devices will get an address in the 192.168.**1**.X range.

Sometimes a router reboot will fix it, but not so much lately.

I can't think of any changes around the time this started happening that could be relevant. A few new devices were added to the router DHCP, but just a phone and tablet.

If it matters, I am using a Nighthawk EX7300 as an access point (connected to the R7000 by cable) to extend the reach, but I haven't changed anything with this for more than a year, and it also happens to an Ubuntu PC connected directly to the R7000 by cable.

The R7000 is on firmware V1.0.9.88_10.2.88.

The EX73000 is on firmware V1.0.2.144 (but just upgraded, it also happened on V1.0.2.140).

Hope anyone has an idea of why this happens, and at least as importantly, how to make it stop!

/Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

- Somehow your EX7300 got DHCP re-enabled.  Turn it back off.

or

- Your subnet mask on your router is something other than 255.255.255.0 (maybe 255.255.254.0) and your DHCP server is actually handing out valid IPs.

Comment: I think you might be correct. It was written a bit weirdly (to me, at least), but I changed the AP setting from "Dynamically get IP address from router" to "Use static IP address". I'll just let it run for a day or so to see how it performs, but I think that might be it.
At least it isn't the subnet on the router.